# Minimum runnable example for ReactiveUI - not running

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I wanted to generate a MWE for my ReactiveUI problem. However I came across new problems.

This is what i tried:

```
using System;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;

namespace ReactivUI_Test
{
    class BarClass : ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive] public String Baz { get; set; } = "";
        public BarClass(String b) { Baz = b; }
        public BarClass() { Baz = "!!!"; }
        public override String ToString() { return Baz.ToString(); }
    }



    class FooClass : ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive] public BarClass Bar { get; set; } = new BarClass();
        public override String ToString() { return Bar.ToString(); }
    }


    class ViewModel: ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive] FooClass Foo { get; set; } = new FooClass();

        public ViewModel()
        {
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Foo.Bar.Baz)
                 .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Hallo " + x?.ToString()));          // <- Runtime Error in this line

            Console.WriteLine("Example 1");
            this.Foo.Bar.Baz = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Example 2a");
            this.Foo.Bar = new BarClass();
            Console.WriteLine("Example 2b");
            this.Foo.Bar = new BarClass();
            Console.WriteLine("Example 3");
            this.Foo.Bar = new BarClass() { Baz = "Something" };

            Console.WriteLine("Example 4");
            this.Foo = new FooClass() ;

            Console.WriteLine("Finish");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

The runtime error I get is:

> **TypeLoadException:** The method "GetActivationForView" of Typ
>   "ReactiveUI.ActivationForViewFetcher" der Assembly "ReactiveUI.WPF,
>   Version=9.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" has no 
>   Implementation.

Comment: I tried your code in a new Fullframework 4.7.2 WPF app, ref ReactiveUi v 11.1.1 and pasted your code into the MainWindow.xaml.cs. The output is as expected, and no error. What type of project are you using? Maybe upgrade?

Comment: @OzBob: Thanks for testing. Found the root cause of problem (missing nuget-package).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found:

Nuget packet: ReactiveUI.WPF was not installed.

Now working as pure console application.

Output:

```
Hallo !!!
Example 1
Hallo
Example 2a
Hallo !!!
Example 2b
Example 3
Hallo Something
Example 4
Hallo !!!
```