# ReactiveUI: IObservable.Transform() does not forward Notifications

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

In the sniplet below, it seems like `transform(x => x.Bar.Baz)` only forwards changes if items in `sl2` are added or removed, but not if th value of `Baz` is changed. Is this expected behaviour? How to change it, that all modifications are found in `transformed`?

```
SourceList<FooClass> sl2 = new SourceList<FooClass>();    
sl2.Connect()
        .Transform(x => x.Bar.Baz)
        .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String> transformed)
        .Subscribe( x=> { Console.WriteLine("CHANGE from Subscribe"); } );
```

The full code reads as. Running example also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/BerndGit/ReactivUI_Test_GH/tree/master/ReactivUI_Test)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using DynamicData;
using DynamicData.Binding;
using ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;

namespace ReactivUI_Test
{
    class BarClass : ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive] public String Baz { get; set; } = "";

        public BarClass(String b) { Baz = b; }
        public BarClass() { Baz = "!!!"; }

        public override String ToString() { return Baz.ToString(); }
    }



    class FooClass : ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive] public BarClass Bar { get; set; } = new BarClass();

        public override String ToString() { return Bar.ToString(); }
    }


    class ViewModel: ReactiveObject
    {
        [Reactive] FooClass Foo { get; set; } = new FooClass();

        void PrintList<T> (IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {


            Console.WriteLine("===  ===");

            SourceList<FooClass> sl2 = new SourceList<FooClass>();

            FooClass fo1 = new FooClass() { Bar = new BarClass("Hello ") };
            FooClass fo2 = new FooClass() { Bar = new BarClass("World ") };
            FooClass fo3 = new FooClass() { Bar = new BarClass("Out ") };
            FooClass fo4 = new FooClass() { Bar = new BarClass("There ") };
            FooClass fo5 = new FooClass() { Bar = new BarClass("!!!!!!") };

            sl2.Add(fo1);
            sl2.Add(fo2);
            sl2.Add(fo3);
            sl2.Add(fo4);


            sl2.Connect()
                .Transform(x => x.Bar.Baz)
                .Bind(out ReadOnlyObservableCollection<String> transformed)
                .Subscribe( x=> { Console.WriteLine("CHANGE from Subscribe"); } );

            Console.WriteLine("=== Start ===");

            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)transformed).CollectionChanged += 
                new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(( s,e) => Console.WriteLine("CHANGE from Event Handler"));


            Console.WriteLine("sl2: ");
            PrintList<FooClass>(sl2.Items);

            Console.WriteLine("transformed: ");
            PrintList<String>(transformed);


            Console.WriteLine("=== Send to Space ===");
            fo2.Bar.Baz = "Space";

            Console.WriteLine("sl2: ");
            PrintList<FooClass>(sl2.Items);

            Console.WriteLine("transformed: ");
            PrintList<String>(transformed);      

            Console.WriteLine("=== Add !!!! ===" );

            sl2.Add(fo5);

            Console.WriteLine("sl2: ");
            PrintList<FooClass>(sl2.Items);

            Console.WriteLine("transformed: ");
            PrintList<String>(transformed);

            Console.WriteLine("===  ===");

            Console.WriteLine("Finish");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }


    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is not what I have hoped for. It seems that `.Transform(x => x.Bar.Baz)` only forwards updates items are added or removed from the list 'sl2'. If there are value changes of `Bar.Baz`, these changes are not forwaded to `transformed`.

My Output is:

```
===  ===
CHANGE from Subscribe
=== Start ===
sl2:
Hello
World
Out
There
transformed:
Hello
World
Out
There
=== Send to Space ===
sl2:
Hello
Space
Out
There
transformed:
Hello
World      <--- I would have hoped to have 'Space' here
Out
There
=== Add !!!! ===
CHANGE from Event Handler   <-- I would have hoped that event handlers are triggered at World->Space
CHANGE from Subscribe       <-- I would have hoped that event handlers are triggered at World->Space
sl2:
Hello
Space
Out
There
!!!!!!
transformed:
Hello
World    <--- I would have hoped to have 'Space' here
Out
There
!!!!!!
===  ===
Finish
```

Note that:
(1) in `transformed` the change of World->Space is never done. In `sl2` this change is done.

(2) The CollectionChangedEvent is only triggered after adding of in Item added.

My question:

How to ensure that `transform()` sets the correct notifications?

**Update**

Based on the of Funk answer below, this should be fixed by:

```
sl2.Connect()
   .AutoRefresh(x => x.Bar.Baz)
   .Transform(x => x.Bar.Baz)
   ...
```

However this does not change the output.

Comment: Did you try the `WhenAnyPropertyChanged` extension method?

Comment: I tried it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59511372/minimum-runnable-example-for-reactiveui-not-running   Basically the ´BarClass´ is firing a notification, in case of ´Baz` is changed.   However I prefer to use the solution using ´transform()´ since I need to use further steps like filtering and sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this expected behaviour?

It is. In line with `ObservableCollection<T>` only changes to the collection (or stream) are monitored.

Of course, what you want is quite common and, luckily, easy to achieve. From the ReactiveUI [documentation](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/#tracking-changes-in-collections-of-reactive-objects):

> DynamicData supports change tracking for classes that implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface — ReactiveObjects. For example, if you'd like to do a WhenAnyValue on each element in a collection of changing objects, use the AutoRefresh() DynamicData operator

Simply add the `AutoRefresh` operator to the pipeline and use the `Transform` operator overload that accepts a flag to set `transformOnRefresh` to true.

```
sl2.Connect()
   .AutoRefresh(x => x.Bar.Baz)
   .Transform(x => x.Bar.Baz, true)
   ...
```

---

Note to aid in debugging, you can decompose the `IChangeSet<string>` and its `Change<string>`s.

```
sl2.Connect()
   .AutoRefresh(x => x.Bar.Baz)
   .Transform(x => x.Bar.Baz, true)
   .Do(x =>
   {
       foreach (var c in x) Console.WriteLine($"sl2 ticks {c.Item.Current}");
   })
   ...
```

Comment: Hello Funk!  Thank you for your answer. Your explaination sounds reasonable. I tried it out, but unfortunatly my output didn't change. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe it is also related to this issue: https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/issues/220    ... (althrough it seems to be closed on Github)?

Comment: This looks like the correct solution. However,   the transform operator does not by default respond to refresh notifications and you need to opt into that. You do so by using ' Transform(x=>x.Bar.Baz, true)'

Comment: @BerndGit In your GitHub repo you didn't add the `.Baz` at the end of `.AutoRefresh(x => x.Bar.Baz)`. Combined with `transformOnRefresh: true` it'll give the desired result.

Comment: Now Working. Thank you Funk and Roland Pheasant!